# Prove that $(\frac{k+1}{k})^{k}\le(\frac{n-k}{n-k-1})^{n-k-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am looking to prove $$(\frac{k+1}{k})^{k}\le(\frac{n-k}{n-k-1})^{n-k-1}$$ When $0<k<\frac{n}{2}$ and both $k$ and $n$ are natural numbers.

It is certainly true that the $(\frac{k+1}{k})^{k}<e$ and from looking at a graphing app it seems that $(\frac{n-k}{n-k-1})^{n-k-1}>e$ when treated as a function of $k$, and $n$ being a constant.

Another observation is that $$0<k<\frac{n}{2}\\ \implies k+1 \le n-k \\ \implies k\le n-k-1$$

So both the numerator, demoninator, and exponent of the LHS are lower than that of the RHS. But because the denominator is also lower, that's not conclusive.

EDIT: I just saw the book says induction so I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already observed, we just need to prove that the function $\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^{x}$ is increasing for $x\gt 0$ and to do that, take the logarithmic derivative and show that it is positive.

Comment: I don't understand how proving that function is increasing will prove the question's problem

Comment: If you showed that this function is increasing, then we have $$\left(\dfrac{k+1}{k}\right)^k\le \left(\dfrac{N+1}{N}\right)^N$$ for any $k\le N$ integers and choose $N$ appropriately. Does that helpful?

Comment: So we've established that $k<n-k-1$, and since the function above is increasing, the choice for $N$ in the latter is $n-k-1$. I understand